# Missing $ inserted underscore sign

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Here is my snippet from LaTeX doc i am creating:

```
54 \subsection{Definicja}
55 Interpolacją nazywamy czynności, których celem jest znalezienie wartości pewnej 
   funkcji \textit{f(x)} w dowolnie wybranym punkcie z przedziału x_{0}, x_{n}
```

I keep getting error:

```
konstrukcja.tex:55 Missing $ inserted ...dowolnie wybranym punkcie z przedziału x_
```

I am new to LaTeX so I have no idea what does it mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap mathematical expressions in `$...$`.  Since you did not know that it is best for you to read a basic introduction to LaTeX.  There are a lot of references listed in these two questions on [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com):

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11)
- [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384)

My personal favourite is [»LaTeX and friends« by M. van Dongen](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642238154).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Definicja}
Interpolacją nazywamy czynności, których celem jest znalezienie wartości pewnej 
funkcji $f(x)$ w dowolnie wybranym punkcie z przedziału $x_{0}$, $x_{n}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Missing $ inserted" is probably caused by the underscores

Try:

```
przedziału x\_{0}, x\_{n}
```

Comment: This workaround probably doesn't produce the intended rendering.

Comment: That solves problem with warning but I need to get lower indexes